# Strange symbols instead of icons in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I am running Firefox 27.0 and sometimes it shows strange symbols instead of icons.

For example, instead of arrows up/down for up voting or down voting in a forum, it show some Japanese looking character.

Comment: Have you got NoScript installed, or any similar addon that may block custom fonts? If so, you will have to allow them using the addon's menu, if possible.

Comment: Yes, I have NoScript, I'll check its settings.

Comment: Done, NoScript > Options > Embeddings > Forbid @font-faces (unmarked). I hope I haven't just open the door for evil fonts to my system.

Comment: Ok, did that solve the problem? An alternative to allowing fonts on all sites would be to either allow scripts for that site or if scripts are already allowed, to allow the specific font under "Blocked Objects".

Comment: Nope, allowing fonts for all works better for me, since the problem arises in many sites.

Comment: Did you set the charset of your document? Do you have a proper doctype?